# Unwanted padding around an image in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8

Hi I am getting unwated bottom padding around an image nested inside an anchor, span, table cell (see jsfiddle link below).

The image is 16x16, but the anchor and span seem to be 16x19 in IE8. Seems to work/look good in IE7 and Chrome (not tested in FF).

Have tried numerous things, but can't shake it!

```
<table class="sequence">
<tr>
    <th>Test</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <span>
            <a href="#">
                <img class="icon" alt="" src="" />
            </a>
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fK8Nc/)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `display: block;` to `img.icon` fixed the problem for me (tested in Internet Explorer 8 on Windows 7).

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fK8Nc/1/)